# Cannot resolve symbol'@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay'

Tags: xml, android-studio

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" & app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay",they have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Something might have gone wrong  while compiling , reopen and reindex the project by  Try to fix by Invavidate Caches/Restart

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
```

Please see if this might help you ...